# jquery .get not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i am trying to display to contents of this test.html file by ajax and the jquery get function as an alert in index.html. The alert out side the .get works.

*test.html*

```
<p>herro my name is dog</p>
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning jQuery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>

alert("data");
$.get("test.html", function(data){
    alert(data);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a webserver, and not just on the local file system ?

Comment: Yes its on a webserver, i am connected to the server properly. Can edit both the files

Comment: What does the URL you are using look like, and what browser?

Comment: If you go into the Network tab of Developer Tools, does it show a successful call to `test.html`?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code it is working for me.

Comment: have you place both these files in same directory and your test.html does not contains anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Developer tools` by hitting F12. This should work in IE8+, FF, and Chrome.

View the `Console` and it should show you the error and point to an offending line of code. This should give you the information you need to fix or do further research.

It works for me in IE11.

Use a debugger to first confirm that jQuery is loading correctly. You can also do this with code:

`alert("jQuery loaded OK? " + $ && typeof($) === 'function' && $ === jQuery);`

Comment: I only get this warning.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Comment: Try to test for jQuery (see above example) first. You may have better luck downloading the jQuery library and installing it on your server. There are other benefits to this, like that you get to manage the versions yourself, and you are not relying on a third party server.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my previous answer, I was alluding to something and should have just been a comment. Also this answer is based on a hunch I have about your situation. If you try:

```
$.get("test.html", function(data){
    alert(data);
}).fail(function() {
    alert('ERROR');
});
```

You should at least have something returned to you even if it's not what you expected. If you then get your ERROR message you can then check your browser's console. You may see something like the following.

[image: Error Capture]

I am suspecting that you are not running this within a web server on your local computer so "test.html" cannot be accepted. You may want to check out a project such as WAMP if you are on Windows or MAMP if you are using a Mac.

If the message isn't like the one shown then update us on what you are getting.